# Bash variable in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to pass variable in loop with awk command to find values. I have a file:

input.txt

```
1234|something|ohmygod
2345|urabura|kangura
9999|1234|xxxsecrets
```

shell command

```
cat input.txt | awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /1234/'
```

or

```
awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /1234/' input.txt
```

get first line from file as desired. Problem occurs when I try to print this via bash. When I simply test echo like:

```
echo `cat input.txt | awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /1234/'`
```

or

```
echo `awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /1234/' input`
```

I got desired output, but unfortunately when I try to pass variable inside it

```
variable1="1234"
echo `awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /"$variable1"/' input`
```

or

```
variable1="1234"
echo `awk -v var="$variable1" -F'|' '$1 ~ /var/' input`
```

it gives one empty line. Please suggest how to pass variable inside regex awk filter.

PS It is not duplicate question to: [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) due to fact that I have knowledge how to use variable in AWK as I posted up here (-v parameter) but the question is how to PASS variable in REGEX in AWK (place between two slashes - echo `awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /"$variable"/' input`)

Comment: As an aside, `echo $(cmd)` is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) unless you specifically require the shell to perform  whitespace tokenization and variable substitution on the output from `cmd`. (The older syntax with backticks ` \`cmd\` ` is obsolescent and should be avoided.

Comment: I have to add echo because I want to debug changes.

Comment: It doesn't do that, it introduces new hard-to-debug corner cases.

Comment: @tripleee but shell does not have any variable "watcher" so how to debug my changes?

Comment: You're probably looking for `set -x`

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for:

```
awk -v var="$variable1" -F'|' '$1 ~ var' input
```

What you actually need:

```
awk -v var="$variable1" -F'|' '$1 == var' input
```

See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Comment: Unfortunately changing ~ to "" does not help.

Comment: That's not what Ed is suggesting.

Comment: @WontProvide where do you see `~` being changed to `""`?

Comment: @EdMorton my typo, I mean ==

Comment: Changing `~` to `==` wasn't intended to answer the question you asked, that's what changing `/var/` to `var` does. Changing `~` to `==` makes it a full string comparison instead of a partial regexp comparison and so avoids false matches.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh, thank you. Unfortunately I'm still looking for an answer how to pass variable to regexp comparison.

Comment: @WontProvide did you try what I showed you? That first script **IS** how to pass a variable for a regexp comparison. `~` is the regexp comparison operator and `var` is the variable.